# byte and short data types in Java can accept the value outside the range by explicit cast. The higher data types however can not. Why?

Tags: java

Let's consider the following expressions in Java.

```
byte a = 32;
byte b = (byte) 250;
int i = a + b;
```

This is valid in Java even though the expression `byte b = (byte) 250;` is forced to assign the value 250 to `b` which is outside the range of the type **byte**. Therefore, b is assigned **-6** and consequently `i` is assigned the value **26** through the statement `int i = a + b;`.

---

The same thing is possible with *short* as follows.

```
short s1=(short) 567889999;
```

Although the specified value is outside the range of *short*, this statement is legal.

---

The same thing is however wrong with higher data types such int, double, folat etc and hence, the following case is invalid and causes a compile-time error.

```
int z=2147483648;
```

This is illegal, since the range of *int* in Java is from **-2,147,483,648** to **2147483647** which the above statement exceeds and issues a compile-time error. Why is such not wrong with *byte* and *short* data types in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in the literal itself. You can do:

```
int z = (int) 2147483648L;
```

because now you've got a "long" literal. So basically, there are two steps involved:

- Parsing the literal to a valid value for that literal type (`int` in your earlier examples, `long` for the "big" one)
- Converting that value to the target type

Answer (score 3):

The error is because by default all numeric integer literals are `int` and `2147483648` is out of range.

To code this, you need to make it a `long` with an explicit downcast to `int`:

```
    int z = (int)2147483648L; // compiles
```